# How do i check if session_start has been entered?

Tags: php

I have a third party script and was wondering how I can check with `PHP` if `session_start()` has been declared before doing something?

```
something like if(isset($_session_start())) { //do something }
```

Comment: Yes, but this was asked 3 years ago. That question was asked 2 years ago.

Comment: Refer to [Check if PHP session has already started](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6249707/6521116)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45397494/4416726) out

Comment: I just always do @session_start(); and who cares - one line - if it is started, you don't care... if it isn't, well it is now. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 43):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();
}
```

The check will allow you to keep your current session active even if it's a loop back submission application where you plan to reuse the form if data is typed incorrectly or have additional checks and balances within your program before proceeding to the next program.

Comment: i'd reccomend to use `if(session_id() == '')`, since `$_SESSION` can be set while the session is closed.

Comment: True, but all $_SESSION['variables'] are set to null when the session starts.  Also, session_id()s are client side cookie values.  It's up to the developer how session data is utilized.

Comment: @Maarek Every time `session_start()` is called, the session variables ARE NOT all set to null.  And when a session is closed (by exiting the script or by calling `session_write_close()`) the session data still persists. In such cases your check is not sufficient, because it will not restart a closed session.

Comment: Also, you can call `session_start()` and then never set `$_SESSION`. Therefore your check will tell you that `session_start()` was never called, which is incorrect.

Comment: A useful answer if there's only one session and not much advanced it done with it, but not great for more complex environments.

Comment: In PHP version above 5.4.0 DON'T USE ```if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();``` or ```if(session_id() === "") session_start();```. They will not work properly after a call to ```session_write_close()``` & continue to report, that the session exists. Instead use ```if(session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)``` & ```if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE)``` or compare to INT numbers i.e. _ACTIVE = 2, _NONE=1 and _DISABLED=0. Alternatively, if you have to, call ```@session_start();``` to supress "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()" warning.

Answer (score 34):

As in PHP >= 5.4.0, you have function session_status() that tell you if it have been initialize or not or if it's disabled.

For example you can do:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  session_start();
}
```

You can read more about it in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

Answer (score 13):

I suppose you could use the [`session_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) function :

> `session_id()` returns the session id
>   for the current session or the empty
>   string ("") if there is no current
>   session (no current session id
>   exists).

Or maybe testing whether `$_SESSION` is set or not, with [`isset`](http://php.net/isset), might do the trick, as it should not be set when no session has been started -- you just have to hope that nothing assigns anything to `$_SESSION` without starting the session first.

Comment: Use session_status() instead of session_id() from PHP 5.4.0. The $_SESSION won't work properly after calling a session_write_close() function.

Answer (score 9):

for php >= 5.4.0

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
session_start();
}
```

for php < 5.4.0

```
if(session_id() == '') {
session_start();
}
```

Comment: This is the recommended method. [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php)

Comment: Note that the < 5.4.0 solution is pretty much useless. session_id() will always return an empty string until session_start() is called. It's called every time.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_SESSION)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function session_started(){ return !!session_id(); }
```

Comment: Don't be too clever ;). I'd prefer 'return (session_id() !== "")'.

Answer (score 0):

If session already started,
Error: "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context"

Try this:

```
$session = session_id();
if(empty($session)){ 
    session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a simple function for it.

```
  function isSessionStart ()
  {
    if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '<')) {
      if(session_id() == '') {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
    else {
      if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    if(defined('SID'))
        // do
```

Answer (score -1):

best way work for me!
    if(session_status() != 1) 
    session_start();

Comment: 1 mean still session is not started, its in none position.