# How to detect whether session_start() has been called in PHP?

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do i check if session_start has been entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788202/how-do-i-check-if-session-start-has-been-entered)

Is there such an API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find out by calling the following code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION))
{
    //The session was started
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `session_write_close()` ends the session mechanism but doesn't destroy _SESSION.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  As VolkerK points out, `$_SESSION` can still be set even though the session has been closed.  And nothing prevents a user from declaring $_SESSION without starting a session. A better check would be: `if (session_id())` (For PHP versions < 5.4.0) or
`if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_NONE)` (For PHP versions >= 5.4.0)

Comment: Also, you can call `session_start()` without ever setting $_SESSION. Your check will then tell you that `session_start()` was never called, which is incorrect.