# Test if session is started

Tags: php, session, isset

How do you test to see if sessions are on. This is not the way...

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION)) {
    echo "sessions ON<br>";
}
else{
    echo "sessions OFF<br>";
}

session_destroy();
if(isset($_SESSION)) {
    echo "sessions ON<br>";
}
else{
    echo "sessions OFF<br>";
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45397494/4416726)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

> if(session_id())

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Answer (score 2):

`session_start()` itself will return boolean TRUE if the session was started successfully, boolean FALSE if not.