# I need to know session_start has used before?

Tags: php, cookies

I have very big stack of code.
I need to use session_start() function always.
If I hasn't used session_start() not run each other.

example:

```
<?php 
if(session_start() == "used")
{
       // not run
}
else
{
       session_start();
}
?>
```

Comment: include it in your config file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you mean, u want to check if the session has already been started? you can get it from here

[Check if PHP session has already started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249707/php-a-better-way-to-check-if-session-has-already-started)

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    // session isn't started
}
```

Comment: This not for only session_start(). I think php programmers need check functions has used or not.

Comment: then you might save something in the session itself - like $session->used = true and check that before calling the functions....

Comment: @Birlikisgu I cannot imagine any reason why you would want to remember whether a function has been called. When you do need that, you're doing something wrong. Please provide an example (in your question) so you can get decent advise. Putting a `if (functionUsed) return;` on top of every function is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(session_id() === ""){
   session_start();
}
```

Comment: How can i use this for other functions?

Comment: Just copy it and paste where you want to start session. It will check if session is not already started.

Comment: If you want to add more code, add that under `session_start();`

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be better to use this top of the page.There is no need to use this sevral time.

```
session_start();
```

Comment: I have 23 classes. I'm using session_start() in my classes.

Comment: @Birlikisgu then change your architecture. A class should not rely on sessions, and besides that, you _must_ have a point-of-entry for your application (i.e. an `index.php` or `config.php`). Put the `session_start()` there.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    `session_start();`
}

Answer (score 1):

you can try it this way:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {    
    session_start();
}
```

See also the [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) documentation

Answer (score 0):

I think this won't work because you need to do a `session_start()` before any line of code