# Is it possible to disable refresh button in php?

Tags: php, html, css, timer

Im creating a Online Examination.. i got my timer for 30 mins it will automatically  submit the exam but every time the page is refresh or reloaded the times resumes at 30mins is there any way to preven it? thanks in advance

```
   <?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['targetdate'])) {
    // session variable_exists, use that
    $targetDate = $_SESSION['targetdate'];
} else {
    // No session variable, red from mysql
    $result=mysql_query("select * from test where testid='29' LIMIT 1");
    $time=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $dateFormat = "d F Y -- g:i a";
    $targetDate = time() + ($time['duration']*60);
    $_SESSION['targetdate'] = $targetDate;

}

$actualDate = time();
$secondsDiff = $targetDate - $actualDate;
$remainingDay     = floor($secondsDiff/60/60/24);
$remainingHour    = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24))/60/60);
$remainingMinutes = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24)-         ($remainingHour*60*60))/60);
$remainingSeconds = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24)-    ($remainingHour*60*60))-($remainingMinutes*60));
$actualDateDisplay = date($dateFormat,$actualDate);
$targetDateDisplay = date($dateFormat,$targetDate);

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var days = <?php echo $remainingDay; ?>  
var hours = <?php echo $remainingHour; ?>  
var minutes = <?php echo $remainingMinutes; ?>  
var seconds = <?php echo $remainingSeconds; ?> 
function setCountDown ()
{
 seconds--;
 if (seconds < 0){
    minutes--;
    seconds = 59
 }
 if (minutes < 0){
     hours--;
     minutes = 59
 }
  if (hours < 0){
  hours = 23
 }
  document.getElementById("remain").innerHTML = "  "+hours+" hr "+minutes+" min    "+seconds+" sec";
  SD=window.setTimeout( "setCountDown()", 1000 );
  if (minutes == '00' && seconds == '00') { seconds = "00"; window.clearTimeout(SD);
    window.location = "result.php"
} 

  }
 </script>

</head>
<body onLoad="setCountDown();">
 <div id="remain"><?php echo "$remainingHour hours, $remainingMinutes minutes,      $remainingSeconds seconds";?></div>
```

I just copy this code i want to limit the quiz timer for only 30 mins and what is $_SESSION['targetdate']??

Comment: Do you have any sort of code? I just can't see the picture with that description.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make countdown timer to not reset on page refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272190/how-to-make-countdown-timer-to-not-reset-on-page-refresh)

Comment: yes sir but i dont understand the $_SESSION target date and the other fields of the TEST DB'

Comment: sir it works!!! but how does the time will reset if other user take the exam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  PHP is a server side language and has no influence at all over the client.

Even if it was possible, doing so would only annoy users.  When they press the refresh button they expect the page to refresh

Comment: so is there any other posible way to have a timer that doesnt reset the time even if it is reloaded or refreshed?

Comment: i mean the refresh button of the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can catch updating in browser by onbeforeunload event listener https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload