# How to use session_start in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I'm creating a bilingual site and have decided to use `session_start` to determine the language of the page using the following:

```
session_start();    
if(!isset($_SESSION['language'])){
    $_SESSION['language'] = 'English'; //default language
}
```

The problem with this is that it clashes with Wordpress and I get the following:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cookie - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/neurosur/public_html/v2/wp-content/themes/default/header.php:8)
>   in /home/neurosur/public_html/v2/wp-content/themes/default/region.php
>   on line 13

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Sure, don't do any output before calling session_start(). Which means you need to buffer everything WP produces up until the session_start call, or insert your session_start earlier in the rendering chain.

Comment: @MarcB I've tried this several times but can never manage to get it to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've changed my original answer to the correct one from @rafi (see below).

Write the following code in your functions.php file:

```
function register_my_session()
{
  if( !session_id() )
  {
    session_start();
  }
}

add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
```

Comment: Editing the header.php file assumes he's not writing a plugin, etc. Really bad hack.

Comment: This is a bad practice check other answers!

Answer (score 54):

**EDIT**

Wordpress sends header info before the header.php file is run. So starting the session in the header.php may still conflict with the header info that wordpress sends. Running it on init avoids that problem. (*From jammypeach's comment*)

Write the following code in your functions.php file:

```
function register_my_session()
{
  if( !session_id() )
  {
    session_start();
  }
}

add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
```

Now if you want to set data in session, do like this

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'rafi';
```

Comment: There is an error in your code, you forgot the semicolon after session_start(). You should correct it.

Comment: this is the better answer - wordpress sends headers before the header.php file is run, so starting the session there may still clash with the headers wordpress sends. Running it on init avoids that problem.

Comment: init hook is better for session_start.

Answer (score 14):

I found an interesting article by Peter [here](http://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/). I'm using the following code in my `functions.php`:

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

This destroys old session when user logs out then in again with different account.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18542272/2363481) and the answers given here, it's best to use the following code snippets:

For versions of **PHP >= 5.4.0, PHP 7**:

```
function register_my_session() {
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
```

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

---

For versions of **PHP < 5.4.0**:

```
function register_my_session() {
    if(session_id() == '') {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

---

I don't want to take any credits, I just felt like sharing this information would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

for PHP version 7.4

```
function register_my_session() {

    if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE && session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
        @session_start();
    } 
} 
add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('init', 'customSessionStart', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'customSessionDestroy');
add_action('wp_login', 'customSessionDestroy');
function customSessionStart()
{
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
function customSessionDestroy()
{
    session_destroy();
}
```

When you use this code, you may get the critical issue in the WP Site Health Status. The error says that;

> A PHP session was created by a `session_start()` function call. This interferes with REST API and loopback requests. The session should be closed by `session_write_close()` before making any HTTP requests.

To suppress this error, you may make this revision when you want to start a session in the WP;

```
session_start([
    'read_and_close' => true,
]);
```

Comment: Setting 'read_and_close' will only be helpful if you don't need to make any changes to the $_SESSION data at a later point. Calling 'read_and_close' will cause any attempt to store data to $_SESSION after calling session_start(['read_and_close' => true]) to silently fail.