# how to start session in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

i am new in wordpress i am want to start a session in wordpress i am using this code in theme head to start session

```
<?php 
add_action('init', 'register_my_session');                                  


// session function                     
function register_my_session(){
    if( !session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}

// calling session function                                 
register_my_session();                      
?>
```

if this code is ok then where i have to add this code in wordpress to start session

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use session\_start in Wordpress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797351/how-to-use-session-start-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place it in your child themes functions.php or create a plugin file for it.