# How to start session safely in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I have referred this question [how to start session in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759867/how-to-start-session-in-wordpress)

With this code generated below critical issue.

```php
<?php 
add_action('init', 'register_my_session');                                  

// session function                     
function register_my_session(){
    if( !session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}

// calling session function                                 
register_my_session();                      
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So here I tried below snippet and critical issue resolved.

```php
<?php
function register_my_session(){
  if( ! session_id() ) {
    session_start();
  }
}
if(!is_admin())
{
  add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
}
?>
```