# Session data working on local test server, but doesn't work once uploaded to internet

Tags: php, session, session-variables

im having a problem with a website iv been working on locally using easyphp server. I have now uploaded it to a webserver and where it was all working before, now I am getting php errors such as :

```
Call to undefined function session_status() in /home/site/public_html/index.php on line 2
```

Its only a simple script on the index page, but all of the other pages are suffering from the same session error problems, but it works locally which makes it even ore odd.

```
    <?php
    if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();}
    if (isset($_SESSION['key'])) {$sessionkey = $_SESSION['key'];}else {$sessionkey = '';}
    if ($sessionkey == 'sbhjbKA2bsbhjbKA209bhjbKA2bsbhjbKA209KaXff19u0bsbhjbKA209KaXff19u9Ka'){
         echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/template/template.css" />';
    include 'connectmysqli.php';
    include 'menu.php';

    }
    else
    {echo '<h1 style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color:red;">Access Denied !</h1>';}
    ?>
```

Comment: Are you using PHP version 5.4 to upper in your local server???
Function `session_status()` only for PHP 5.4 or upper

Comment: check your PHP version on server, as PHP5.4 and above have session_status

Comment: @Satya, PHP 5.3 still does not included this function.
http://hk.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

Comment: mea culpa @Allen, just edited my answer, apologies

Comment: Check this answer from Miruyu, it's fast and easy [easy and fast solution from maruyu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684397/9143130)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`session_status`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php) was introduced in PHP 5.4. Check your server's PHP version.

You could do without that call by the way, I'd say. Just always call `session_start`. If your code is riddled with it, just create a function stub.

Comment: Thanks, thats got it !, the server was running on 5.3 !.

Answer (score 3):

Recommended way for versions of PHP >= **5.4.0**

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

For versions of PHP < **5.4.0**

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249707/check-if-php-session-has-already-started)

Answer (score 1):

it need PHP 5.4 ..

if you use xampp you can use this link check php vervion "phpinfo()"