# How do i correct this error Notice: A session had already been started and Undefined index

Tags: php

I need some one to correct me from my mistake here is the error

```
Notice: Undefined index: login in C:\xampp\htdocs\bank\index.php on line 10
Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\bank\index.php on line 10
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bank\header.php on line 2
```

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE loginid='$_POST[login]' AND accpassword='$_POST[password]'");`
`if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)`

Comment: This is **very** prone to SQL injection. Please, use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: Proper session check is `if(session_status()==PHP_SESSION_NONE)` FYI

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['password'],$_POST['login']))
{
    //Your new, safe, PDO/mysqli query
}
```

As for the session, if you don't have varying includes, just remove the duplicate `session_start()`, if the file is sometimes standalone, and sometimes part of the whole project, add the following check:

```
//PHP >= 5.4
if(session_status()==PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();

//PHP < 5.4
if(session_id()=='') session_start();
```

This checks that sessions are enabled, but none have been started.

Information on safer database handling is covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/763371), be sure to check the links in that answer

Comment: if(session_id()=='') session_start(); this worked to solve the session problem

Answer (score 0):

## Session notice

You have a session starting somewhere, and then again in `C:\xampp\htdocs\bank\header.php`'s second line. You should do if **PHP >= 5.4.0**:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  session_start();
  }
```

If **PHP < 5.4.0**:

```
if(session_id() == '') {
  session_start();
  }
```

This can be seen here: [Check if PHP session has already started](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6249707/938236).

## Undefined index and other issues

However, your code has the following issues:

- It is subject to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/938236).
- `mysql_*` is not secure anymore. You should be using PDO or MySQLi for the database handling.
- Are you *seriously* storing passwords in the database as plain text? You need to [properly hash them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/401656).

Fixing it (**PHP >= 5.5**):

```
$DB = new PDO(/* CORRECT PARAMETERS HERE */);
if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
  $STH = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE loginid = ?");
  $STH->execute(array($_POST['login']));
  $Result = $STH->fetch();
  if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $Result['password'])) {
    /* Do what you need to do */
    }
  }
```

For **PHP <= 5.5**, you need to add a library for using `if(password_verify(...))`. Check [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for more info, but it's basically this:

```
include "password_compat.php";

$DB = new PDO(/* CORRECT PARAMETERS HERE */);
if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
  $STH = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE loginid = ?");
  $STH->execute(array($_POST['login']));
  $Result = $STH->fetch();
  if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $Result['password'])) {
    /* Do what you need to do */
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Notice: Undefined index: login` means that in your array, there's no entry with "login" as index. So in your case, that means that $_POST does not contain "login" key.
You have to verify that these indexes exist.

`isset($_POST['login'])` is a good way to do that.

`array_key_exists('login', $_POST)` is another way.

Answer (score -1):

For **Undefined** you need to check if the variable is set or not like this

```
if (isset($_POST[login]) && isset($_POST[password])) {
    // your code here

}
```

For **A session had already been started**

You have already use `session_start()` somewhere else other then `header.php`. so you need to remove it from either of the page

Comment: Never ever do this. It's prone to SQL injection.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia with `isset`

Comment: Your original code (`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE loginid='$_POST[login]' AND accpassword='$_POST[password]'");`) was prone to mysql injection, and that's why I unvoted it.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia actually this was not the requirement of the person ask this the question. First kindly read the question properly, and then Please go and read the Stack overflow manual.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia you need to take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer >> **Answer the question**

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia it is non-sense down voting some one answer when it has noting to do with any error you found in the question. Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia your response here will be appreciated?

Comment: Thank you, I have already read the how-to-answer. Please, refer to [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102536/179259) to know why I downvoted it. If you changed the code to a secure one, I'd upvote it, but just hiding it doesn't make it any more secure. I hope it wasn't you who downvoted me based only on revenge.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Is it really hard to understand that this was not the part of the question?