# Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at

Tags: php, html, mysql

The following warning comes in **login page**: ***Its working in localhost but not in remote host***

**Warning:** session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at  on line 8)

**Warning:** session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at on line 8)

[image]

## index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usr']) && isset($_SESSION['pswd'])){
header('Location: content.php');}
?>
<body>
<center>
<form method='post' action='login.php'>
<!– in this example I link it with login.php to check the password & username–>
<table>
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type='text' name='usr'></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='pswd'></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type='submit' name='login' value='Login'></td>
<td><input type='reset' name='reset' value='Reset'></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>
</body>
```

## content.php

```
<body>
<a href="resumedownload.php">Click here to Download to Resume</a>
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["usr"]) || !isset($_SESSION["pswd"])){
 header('Location: index.php');}
include 'logoff.php';
?>
</body>
```

## login.php

```
<body>
<?php
session_start();
if($_REQUEST['usr']=='suman.trytek' && $_REQUEST['pswd']=='solutions'){
$_SESSION['usr'] = 'suman.trytek';
$_SESSION['pswd'] = 'solutions';
header('Location: content.php');
}
else{
header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Find answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: its  due to  multiple header location send  so you can use at the top after <?php   ob_start();

Comment: In my case I had to set the file encoding without BOM.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Move the `session_start();` to top of the page always.

```
<?php
@ob_start();
session_start();
?>
```

Comment: Check that you aren't saving with BOM (also called a Unicode Signature). I tried everything and BOM was the problem. This is common if you're using UTF-8 files.

Comment: Awesome. It works within a single moment

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was trying this for a while.

Answer (score 10):

1. session_start() must be at the top of your source, no html or other output befor!
2. your can only send session_start() one time
3. by this way `if(session_status()!=PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) session_start()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249707/check-if-php-session-has-already-started

Answer (score 3):

You cannot session_start(); when your buffer has already been partly sent.

This mean, if your script already sent informations (something you want, or an error report) to the client, session_start() will fail.