# Get id of current session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to build a small stats analytic for website, so I created a table in database:

```
| ID | SESSION_ID | DATE_TIME | BROWSER | REFERER | ADDR_IP | FIRST_PAGE | LAST_ACTIVITY
```

And used this PHP code:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

function curPageURL() {
    //// function code
}

function getIpAddr() {
     /// function code
}
function getBrowser() {
     /// function code
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['org_referer'])) {
        if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { 
        $_SESSION['org_referer'] = "(direct) / (none)";
        } else { 
        $_SESSION['org_referer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        } 

    }

if(!isset($_SESSION['first_page'])) {
    $_SESSION['first_page'] = curPageURL();
}

$SESSION_ID = ?
 $BROWSER = getBrowser();
 $REFERER = $_SESSION['org_referer'];
$ADDR_IP = getIpAddr();;
$FIRST_PAGE = $_SESSION['first_page'];
$LAST_ACTIVITY = time();
```

How can I get the current `session_id` ? 
Is the `session_id` unique ? 
I want to update rows with this query:

```
`UPDATE row FROM table WHERE SESSION_ID=$SESSION_ID`
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `session_id()`

```
session_start();    
echo $ses_id = session_id();
```

For more :- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: before session_start(); or after ?

Comment: session must be started before using session_id()

Comment: don't work 
`if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
echo session_id();`

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249707/check-if-php-session-has-already-started

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current session id with `session_id()`