# Cannot set session variables in a page that is handling session.upload_progress.name

Tags: php, session

This has been another one of those hair pulling moments, and I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this issue I'm having.

I've managed to replicate the issue with 2 simple php pages.

**Page1 (test.php)**

This is just a simple file upload form that also uses the `session.upload_progress.name` hidden field. It then outputs the `$_SESSION` array:

```
<form name="fileupload" action="test2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="123">
    <input type="file" name="newfile">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

**Page 2 (test2.php)**
This page simply adds a session variable, and outputs the `$_SESSION` array. It also includes a link to go back to test.php:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION['new']='Im a new value that will disappear';
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
<a href="test.php">Go back</a>
```

Now, if you load `test1.php`, it will output:

```
{ The form }
Array()
```

Click submit, and it will take you to test2.php and output:

```
Array
(
    [upload_progress_123] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 1419385365
             etc etc ...
        )

    )

    [new] => Im a new value that will disappear
)
```

Now click 'Go back' and it will only output:

```
{ the form }
Array
(
    [upload_progress_123] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 1419385365
             etc etc ...
        )

    )
)
```

(Notice how `[new]` is not there)

Is there any solid reason as to why this is happening?

In this example, I have `session.upload_progress.cleanup` set to off, for debugging. But the behaviour of the new session is the same when it is set to on.

Comment: Looks like I'm gunna have to stick a bounty on it ... Just out of curiousity, has anyone copied my code and had the same output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you're checking for an active session before starting one. `session_start()` should be called on every page so you don't really need those `if(!isset($_SESSION))`, if you remove them the page should work correctly.

But if for some reason you must check if the session has been started, the correct way to do so according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18542272/2049063) would be:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the new session dissappears. If I implement your changes into the code, the same results are achieved.

Comment: Strange, I copied your code and replicated the issue. Modified it and it worked correctly. What PHP version are you running?

Comment: v5.5 on Ubuntu Trusty ... When you copied my code, did you manage to replicate the problem?

Comment: Well not completely, the upload progress feature doesn't work on my local server but I did notice the session value set in `test2.php` was not being kept when clicking on the "Go back" link

Comment: Ah yeah you were right, I was implementing your solution wrong ... But, can you explain why this only happens when using the `session.upload_progress.name` as a hidden field? If you remove it from the form, it allows you to add to the current session, using my code.

Comment: Also, thanks Lol ... I can stop pulling my hair out Lol