# condition to check if the session variables as well as get and post have been destroyed in php

Tags: php, session, destroy, unset

The code is like:(It is the last page of the web-app I have made)

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['var'])
{
session_start();
$a=$_SESSION['prev_defined'];
#more use of session variable
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
unset($_GET);
unset($_POST);
}
?>
```

Now when i execute the web application it runs fine , when i refresh the last page whose code is given above the warning message shows of undefined symbol because the `$_SESSION` variables as well as `$_GET` and `$_POST` have been deleted. I want to display message "SESSION OVER" on refresh. How to do it? Where to put if condition? I have tried to put the above code in

```
if($_SESSION)
{
#entire code above
}
else
{
echo"SESSION OVER";
}
```

but it displayes message undefined variable _SESSION

Comment: You need session_start() at the top

Comment: @Farkie i did that in the actual code... still unable to do what i am trying to do

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['var'])
{
  if(isset($_SESSION))
  {
    session_start();
    $a=$_SESSION['prev_defined'];
    #more use of session variable
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION = array();
    unset($_GET);
    unset($_POST);
  }
  else
  {
    echo"SESSION OVER";
  }
}
?>
```

Try this one. If session is set it will do the conditions.

**EDIT**

```
if(isset($_GET['var'])
    {
....
}
else
  {
    echo"SESSION OVER";
  }
```

Using this, If `$_GET['var']` is not set then echo the else part

**EDIT 2**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET) || isset($_SESSION)) {
//Put all your codes here
} else {
    echo "Session Over";
}
```

Comment: how would it solve the purpose on refresh $_GET and $_POST are already unset and hence it will not even enter in th out if loop of isset($_GET['var'])

Comment: Simple. add else part in first if condition also

Comment: I have tried it and it should work but it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION is a global variable, an array. And it will be allways around.

check if session feature is active like so:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_destroy();
    echo "session over";
}
```

Also note to check if arrays key isset, before checking it's value, to avoid notices:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])&&$_SESSION['login']==1){//pass}
```

**EDIT:**

as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249707/check-if-php-session-has-already-started): **For versions of PHP < 5.4.0**

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: I want dt on refresh, when the post and get are unset already and session variables have been deleted..the program should detect it and rather than telling that variable undefined should just output session over.... whn i used
'if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_destroy();
    echo "session over";
}' its showing session over even before refreshing

Comment: because session was not started try printing session_status() with and without session_start() before it.