# Check if session exists in php

Tags: php, session

In my php function here, i want to check if the session exists or not. based on the session existence i want to return true or false.

i have a login function which uses `session_start();` and stores values into session variables when logged in, and when logged out it will do `session_destroy();`

now i want to check if the session exists or not.
How can i do that

```
function ifsessionExists(){
    // check if session exists?
    if($_SESSION[] != ''){
    return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried with `isset()` or `empty()` ?? Remember to start the session for your "check" as well :)

Comment: You want to check if session started or it is empty??

Comment: If you want to check session is started or not 
Prefer this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249707/check-if-php-session-has-already-started

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if PHP session has already started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249707/check-if-php-session-has-already-started)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `isset` function

```
function ifsessionExists(){
// check if session exists?
  if(isset($_SESSION)){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
 }
```

You can also use `empty` function

```
 function ifsessionExists(){
// check if session exists?
  if(!empty($_SESSION)){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
 }
```

Comment: just doing
`return isset($_Session);`
or
`return !empty($_Session);`
does the same with less code (and shouldn't it be "not empty $_Session" in your example?)

Answer (score 7):

Recommended way for versions of PHP >= 5.4.0

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

> Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php
>
> For versions of PHP < 5.4.0

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
function ifsessionExists(){
// check if session exists?
if(isset($_SESSION['Key']) && $_SESSION['Key'] == 'Value'){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `session_id()`.

> session_id() returns the session id for the current session or the empty string ("") if there is no current session (no current session id exists).

```
function ifsessionExists(){
    // check if session exists?
    $sid= session_id();
    return !empty($sid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isset`

```
function ifsessionExists(){
    //check if session exists?
    if (isset($_SESSION['key'])){
    return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function ifsessionExists(){
    // check if session exists?
    if(isset($_SESSION)){
    return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }
}
```

Actualy, this is the better way to do this as suggested on session_status() documentation page:

```
<?php
/**
* @return bool
*/
function is_session_started()
{
    if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
        if ( version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=') ) {
            return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE;
        } else {
            return session_id() === '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

// Example
if ( is_session_started() === FALSE ) session_start();
?>
```

Here you can read more about it https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php#113468