# Multiple ajax requests at the same time

Tags: php, ajax, progress-bar

I have a form that is validated then submitted with the following handler :

```
submitHandler:function (form) {


    $.ajax({
        url: 'long_process.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            // ... Redirect ...
        }
    });


    //start polling
    (function poll() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "get_progress.php",
                success: function (data) {

                    console.log(data);
                    //Setup the next poll recursively
                    poll();
                },
            });
        }, 3000);
    })();


}
```

`long_process.php` takes about 30s to finish and in the meantime I'd like to track the progress via `get_progress.php` which echo the percentage of processing done.

When launching this script I get in the console *(edited)*:

```
1 POST long_process.php
2 GET get_process.php (3 seconds later)...
...stuck here until long_process.php finishes THEN 
3 GET get_process.php (3 seconds later)...
4 GET get_process.php (3 seconds later)...
...
```

but none of the `get_progress.php` return any values until the `long_process.php` is finished.

How can I achieve multiple simultaneous ajax request ? Ultimately this will be used to display a progress bar.

Comment: `get_progress.php` must be returning, because you don't set up the next one until it returns.

Comment: yep true, my mistake. Line 3 and 4 in the console come only once `long_process.php` finishes, THEN first call of `get_process.php` returns a value and every 3 seconds thereafter again...

Comment: Do you use sessions in the scripts? By default only one script can access a session at a time, and it locks the other script out.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190439/if-call-php-page-via-ajax-that-takes-a-while-to-run-return-and-it-sets-session/35190997#35190997 for how to access the same session in multiple scripts.

Comment: I do indeed! Just tested with removing the session in `get_process.php` and it now works ! Thanks, I was far from thinking the problem could be related to that. I have to find a way around using sessions in `get_process.php` now, but that's another problem. Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using sessions in your PHP then the one call will block the other, because PHP won't allow two requests to use the same session space at the same time. Your two requests are probably firing, but you are not getting a request to the second until the server finishes with the first.

To solve this:

Option 1: Don't use sessions in the first script that you are calling or, if you must, then unlock the session using session_write_close(). After calling this, of course, you can't write any session variables.

Option 2: If reading and writing session variables is essential then don't use session variables in the second AJAX call and don't declare a session start. Have your first script put it's status somewhere else for you to read (in a DB, a file on /tmp) and then have the second script read the status from there.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, the problem was indeed in the `session` usage.

Comment: Brilliant! This has been the issue the whole time. Now I can have loading bars.