# single page application session_start error notification

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a single page application based on an `index.php` page where I start the session and display first contents. Then I load via Ajax contents in different divs based on the links that are clicked.

If I want to access the `$_SESSION` array in the loaded page (eg. to display user's name) I need to put `session_start` also in the page that I load via Ajax.
Everything works fine this way but when I see the log I see that php is throwing an error each time I load one of the pages via Ajax saying that

> "session already started. Ignoring session_start()".

So: on one side I need to put session_start to access the session array but on the other the session_start command is ignored.

From index.php:

```
<?php
require '../session_handler.inc.php';
require 'global_functions.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['id1'])){
    $actusr=$_SESSION['id1'];
}
```

A sample ajax call:

```
function loadContent(sourceUrl){
    $(".container").load(sourceUrl);
}
```

The php I need on top of the called page:

```
<?php 
require '../../session_handler.inc.php';
require '../global_functions.php';
session_start();
```

If I remove the session_start() the $_SESSION will be unavailable

How can I fix this situation? Can I access the session array from the loaded page without starting session?

Comment: Try removing it from the ajax as it's part of the script you're running it under.

Comment: @Fred-ii- then I no longer will load $_Session array

Comment: *Hm...*, bizarre. Can you share your code? Can't see how that would break like that. You don't have 2 `session_start();`'s anywhere in the same file(s) do you? Or something else is calling it twice? like an include/require etc. a function somewhere.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no for sure! Will add some sample code

Comment: It's definitely not because you call `session_start` in the first page load and then in the AJAX handlers. Those are independent requests. Most likely you are calling `session_start` twice in your AJAX handlers.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I have already checked it. Also checked the log live while navigating and the issue happen when I load the page. No double session_start() on the same page for sure

Comment: Does `session_handler.inc.php` and/or `global_functions.php` contain `session_start();` or any other file calling it twice? @LelioFaieta check your console also.

Comment: It's most likely in something you `include` in that page where you `session_start`.

Comment: session_handler is an empty file actually and global_functions has no session_start command

Comment: someone popped an answer below, no idea if that'll work for you @LelioFaieta

Comment: This doesn't really address the question, but why are you including an empty file?

Comment: It certainly seems like a file called `session_handler` might start the session.

Comment: @LelioFaieta which he/she might have pulled from http://stackoverflow.com/a/18542272/ and the Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249707/check-if-php-session-has-already-started See also the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

Comment: @Don'tPanic it's a file to manage sessions via db. Since now I have a dedicated and not shared server I am testing sessions without db. Before removing the file I just commented it all to see if it works

Comment: @Fred-ii- if I check for session to be started on the loading page I get a not started feedback anyway i check it. Also if I don't start the session again the $_session array is not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use this line instead of `session_start()`.
you might have more than one session_start and using session between those two.

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: @Fred-ii-, added the description

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. It will run session_start

Comment: @LelioFaieta, What do you have in your session_handler file which you included at the first line?

Comment: It is a completely empty file!

Comment: @LelioFaieta, did you try my solution at all? if yes, please echo session_id() to see what do you get

Comment: As I said your solution leads to run session _start()

Comment: @LelioFaieta, you are wrong. My solution leads to run session_start if it's not already run.
You can try it once

Comment: @LelioFaieta, So, as I mentioned, please echo session_id()

Comment: @LelioFaieta, do you know the logic of if? if it's empty, how it's going to inside of if block and leading to session_dtart(). You are so rude. I am wasting my time to help you and you are offencing me.

Comment: Your code means: if session_id is empty start session. You got it ? You wrote it!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing on a local WAMP or Xamp environment, I would recommend you clear your cache, close your browser (Not a single tab) and run your app.

Try this 1:

```
 <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
        { 
            session_start(); 
        } 
    ?>
```

Or

2: If you have php>=5.4.0, better use this:

```
$status = session_status();
if($status == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    //There is no active session
    session_start();

}else
if($status == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
    //Destroy current and start new one
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I run a webserver for this app. This solution will not solve the issue. I need to pass the session array to the new page in any other way than session _start

Answer (score 0):

move session_start(); to top of your page

```html
<?php
session_start();
require '../session_handler.inc.php';
require 'global_functions.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['id1'])){
    $actusr=$_SESSION['id1'];
}
```

session_handler.inc.php or global_functions.php may already contain session_start() so move the session_start() of index.php to the top. also note that this should be the first statement in index.php

or insert the code below at page top of index.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

and remove the other session_start() in index.php

Comment: Index.php needs session start to check if user has logged in so I can't remove it

Comment: @LelioFaieta   dont remove it just move it to the top of the page just after <?php like <?php                                                                                                            session_start();

Comment: You know that this doesn't change anything? It's not a "headers already sent" issue. The code sequence doesn't affect the result at all (tested)

Comment: @LelioFaieta please try doing the same in the page that you are loading in the div and the index.php page. i faced this similar problem a while back and doing this solved mine.

Comment: It doesn't in my case.