# PHP Session is Null

Tags: php, session, post

How my script works:

1. index.php gets the file sends it to the jscript to analyze it, then it send to the upload.php where the session it should be.

But the Session is null.
if i go to the upload.php and print the variable it shows my usernumber 2(works)

```
require_once("user/upload_session.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start();}
```

Login to create session:

```
public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, user_name, email, pass FROM accounts WHERE user_name=:uname OR email=:umail ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['pass']))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['id'];
                  $thatsmysession = $_SESSION['user_session']; 
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

well im using this:

```
if (empty($thatsmysession)) {
    // Query if user is NOT logged in
    $q = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO files (hash, originalname, filename, size, date, ' .
                      'expire, delid, ip) VALUES (:hash, :orig, :name, :size, :date, ' .
                      ':exp, :del, :ip)');
} else {
          
    // Query if user is logged in (insert user id together with other data)
    $q = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO files (hash, originalname, filename, size, date, ' .
                      'expire, delid, user, ip) VALUES (:hash, :orig, :name, :size, ' .
                      ':date, :expires, :delid, :user, :ip)');
    $q->bindValue(':user', $thatsmysession, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
```

Only there at `$q->bindValue(':user', $thatsmysession, PDO::PARAM_INT);` the session is `null` but if i echo to test if the variable is correct it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check session like this

```
if(session_id() == ''){ session_start();}
```

Instead of this

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start();}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your check for an existing Session is wrong. Try it as mentioned in this thread: 
[Check if PHP session has already started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249707/check-if-php-session-has-already-started)

Comment: Incorrect but still working in all versions I've used it in (5.3.6, 5.4, 5.5 and 5.6)

Comment: this is the same u linked me if if(empty($thatsmysession)) {} else {code}

Answer (score 0):

You can check first if your session exists and also if $_SESSION['user_session'] and it's not empty.

```
if(session_id() == ''){ session_start();}
// check if you user_session exists or not, doLogin
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_session'])){ doLogin(...); }
```

Comment: that was not the problem, i checked it i can echo the session and it gives the correct variable see above i added an block code where the problem is