# Sessions are not working after redirection

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Here is my code for setting sessions in `user-authentication.php`:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['admin_name'] = $name;
$_SESSION['sbc_admin'] = "y";
$_SESSION['admin_email'] = $email;

header("Location:includes/user-auth.php");
```

and here's the code to check whether sessions are set or in `user-auth.php`:

```
session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["sbc_admin"])) {
        $admin = $_SESSION["sbc_admin"];
        $name = $_SESSION["admin_name"];
        $email = $_SESSION["admin_email"];
    } else {
        header("Location:../index.php");
}
```

After redirection, session variables are lost. I have tried a few tricks but it's still not working.

Comment: Make sure you have placed `session_start();` right after opening the php tag.

Comment: What you are getting when you print session ? by print_r($_SESSION) ??

Comment: What "few tricks" have you tried? please include them above.

Comment: Location headers are not meant to be relative.  (To be honest they're not even meant to be absolute to the web root but everybody does it anyway).  They're meant to be complete URLs

Answer (score 0):

Take `session_start();` and place at the top of all of your code. You essentially want it to be one of, if not, the first method to run.

I tend to create a file called `lib.php` which is called into the Header.php document. This lib file contains all object creation, certain functions, etc. The very first bit of code on the page is:

```
<?php
session_start();
//the rest of the code here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You should start the session on all your php files like below code, else you can start session on common file (which file included on all files)

test1.php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['admin_name'] = 'test';
$_SESSION['sbc_admin'] = "y";
$_SESSION['admin_email'] = 'test1';

header("Location:test2.php");
?>

test2.php
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "session_start()" on all pages, you should have a PHP file that is included on all of your php pages. Just like a header or a config file.

You need to check if the session has started and to start the session if not.
You can inspire from this answer to see how to check and start the session in PHP versions that appeared before and after 5.4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18542272/1564840

Comment: Problem solved by restarting server. May be temp of the server was full. After restarting server now everything is working. Thanks to all :)

Comment: next time test with two browsers, the browser cache was your problem

Comment: It was not about browser cache, i am talking about server cache

Comment: Client of the application has installed own server setup rather than buying hosting from re-sellers