# PHPUnit code coverage session already started

Tags: php, html, unit-testing, session, phpunit

I have PHP v7.0.15 PHPUnit v6.0.7.  Running the command `phpunit` alone runs all my tests just fine.

Now I'd like to get information on code coverage, so I made a directory called `phpcoverage` and am running the command `phpunit --coverage-html phpcoverage`.  This outputs the error:

`session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Printer.php:114)`

I read in another answer that I should call `@session_start()` in my tests, so I added that as the first line and now get the error:

`A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()`

My phpunit.xml file looks like this:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="public_html/app/vendor/autoload.php"
  colors="true"
  convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
  convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
  convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
  processIsolation="false"
  stopOnFailure="false"
  syntaxCheck="true">

  <testsuites>
      <testsuite name="App Tests">
          <directory>tests</directory>
      </testsuite>
  </testsuites>

  <filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
      <directory suffix=".php">public_html/app/library</directory>
    </whitelist>
  </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be great if you could link the other answer that suggests so for cross-reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have session_start() called more than once in one page in your code. You can check the session status before you session_start() in your test case. Refer to [Check if PHP session has already started](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6249707/6521116)

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```