# $_Session don't work, how to use it in a proper way?

Tags: php, session-variables

I got a big problem when I tryed to work directly with session...

```
/* session_start(); //already tried */
if (isset($_SESSION) == false)
{
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['PDO'] = new dataBase();
  $_SESSION['Debug'] = 'Inside the isset';  
}
else
{
  $_SESSION['Debug'] = 'Outside the isset';  
}
```

EDIT:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['PDO'])) // the session is new
{ 
  $dbObject = new dataBase(); // store the data into the session
  $_SESSION['PDO'] = $dbObject;
  echo 'I created a session and stored some data into it';
} 
else 
{ // there is data into the session
  var_export($_SESSION);
  echo 'I have some data in the session';  
}
```

The output is always "I created a session and stored some data into it"

I begin to think that the problem may come from my class

```
class dataBase
{
  var $connLink;

  var $SERVERNAME = "127.0.0.1";
  var $PORT = "3388";
  var $USERNAME = "root";
  var $PASSWORD = "";

  function __construct()
  {
    try 
    {
        $this->connLink = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->SERVERNAME;port=$this->PORT;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8", $this->USERNAME, $this->PASSWORD);
        $this->connLink->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo 'Echec lors de la connexion : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: `session_start();` on the top of the page

Comment: M A Siddiqui if I do that I'll never affect my $_SESSION['PDO'] = new dataBase(); ...

Comment: on each page where you want to do anything with SESSION, `session_start();` needed on top of the page just after starting `<?php` tag

Comment: just for my personal culture, using session to store an instance of database object isn't a good way, right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if PHP session has already started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249707/check-if-php-session-has-already-started)

Comment: then check if `$_SESSION['PDO']` is set

Comment: I put my session_start at the top inside a <?php session_start(); ?> And i tried to see if $_Session['PDO'] wasn't set, I set it, else i put an victory message. But I always set the $_Session['PDO'] when i submit or refresh :(

Comment: Thank's harvey_slash i'm sure that it will help me later it's a nice type for instanciate it !

Answer (score 2):

before accessing `$_SESSION` you first need to initialise session using `session_start();` on the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

The `$_SESSION` variable does not exist until `session_start()` is called. This function needs to be called on each page.

Here is what you need to do :

```
session_start(); // start the session

if (!isset($_SESSION['PDO'])) { // the session is new
  $_SESSION['PDO'] = new dataBase(); // store the data into the session
  echo 'I created a session and stored some data into it';
} else { // there is data into the session
  echo 'I have some data in the session';  
}
```

On the first call on the page, the session is started and the pdo data stored into it. Then on the next calls on this page, the session is loaded from the server storage and the pdo data is in the session

Please note that sessions **will not work** if you use php from the command line

Comment: the first time you load the page you will go inside the `isset`. then if you reload it, it will go into the `else`

Comment: Mmmmh my output is always "I created a session and stored some data into it" with that code. I don't unset anything in my dataBase class, i still don't understand

Comment: add this just after the session_start : `echo session_id();` and check if the id is the same when you reload the page

Comment: Yes i go the same id when i reload or input

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['PDO']))
{
  $_SESSION['PDO'] = new dataBase();
  $_SESSION['Debug'] = 'Inside the isset'; 
}
else
{
  $_SESSION['Debug'] = 'Outside the isset';  
}
```

you have something like this ?

EDIT :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['test']))
{
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $_SESSION['test'] = $obj;
}
else{
    var_export($_SESSION);
}
```

try this then

Comment: Except that I change the debug to 'Inside the isset' when i define the $_SESSION['PDO']

Comment: When i assign the class to my $_SESSION, i can't register more data

Answer (score 0):

use `session_start()` before `$_SESSION`
[Click here for more details .....](https://www.facebook.com/WebDeveloperSahajArora)

Comment: Only sublime text with easyPhp

Comment: try this  $session = new Session();

Comment: At the begining ? And what will become $_SESSION ? or you mean is that $_SESSION = new Session()

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decided to never create my object and to use it only by static function
Like dataBase::connectDB(); etc ...