# Why is favicon not showing?

Tags: php, html, favicon

I am having a very strange problem. I have two php files in which I´m using html and there are in the same folder, but in one of that the favicon shows up and in the other it doesn´t. I have checked the code and the code of the two files is almost the same.

This code works:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home</title>
                <link href="../css/topbar2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <link href="../css/home2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
                <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="../img/favicon.jpg">
    </head>
```

In this doesn´t work:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Edit Accounts</title>
        <link href="../css/topbar2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="../css/updateAccount.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="../img/favicon.jpg">
    </head>
```

EDIT: 
I think I know why is this happening. Before my HTML code, I have some php code, that is this:

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
require_once '../constants/sessionVariables.php';
require_once '../db/dbConnection.php';
// Se comprueba que el usuario ha iniciado sesión. Si no es así,
// se le redirige a index.php
if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
}

$loginURL = $gClient->createAuthUrl();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $q = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['q']);
    $f = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['f']);
    $s = $_POST['submit'];
}
?>
```

I came to the conclusion that the error comes from the dbConnection.php file, but I don´t know why. This is the dbConenction.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'configurator';

$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, 
        $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}


ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Comment: Did you reload the page refreshing the cache ? Usually with ctrl + F5

Comment: Why is the icon one directory up and placed in img? It should be in the root of the httpdocs.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I have tried CTRL + F5 and also I have locate it in my root folder and it doesn´t show

Comment: Change to `href="/favicon.jpg"` (remove img path).

Comment: @MarkusZeller I think that that isn´t the problem. Can you check the edit of my post, please?

Comment: Remove the trailing php close tag `?>` at the end of every PHP file. This may produce whitespaces breaking the doctype.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thanks for all of your help, I finally resolved the problem that was the session start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the mistake was that in the dbConenction.php file when it starts the connection because it was already started before by another file. So, what I have done to resolve the problem is to put and if clause before the instruction of sessions start:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
session_start();
}
```

Comment: [You should use this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18542272/3536236)

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the recommendation, I am going to change it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your icon should be in your root folder.
Second, have you tried clearing your browsers cache or reloading the page with CTRL + F5?

Comment: Yes, I have tried CTRL + F5 and also I have locate it in my root folder and it doesn´t show